# I can't top position an h2 tag with css and flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am designing the header of my homepage with react, html and css. In the header I have a button and an h2 tag, each one inside a different div tag. I apply display:flex to these elements and with the justify-content property I try to move them.

In the div that I have the button I have the property: justify-content: end and it positions it at the end of it and that's fine, but in the div that I have the h2 tag, I put justify-content: start and it doesn't position it at the beginning from the div tag. Why does this happen ? what should I do?

EncabezadoHome.tsx:`import {useBlockchain} from "../../hooks/useBlockchain";
import './EncabezadoHome.css'

export const EncabezadoHome = () => {

```
const {wallet, web3Provider, connectWallet} = useBlockchain();

return (
    <header>
        <div className={"container-header-home"}>

            <div className={"logo-header-home"}>
                <h2>Emprendamos</h2>
            </div>

            <div className={"button-header-home"}>
                <button onClick={connectWallet}>Conectar Wallet</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </header>

);
```

};

`

EncabezadoHome.css:

```
.container-header-home {
    display: flex;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.logo-header-home {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    justify-content: start;
}

.logo-header-home h2 {
    padding-left: 20px;
    color: white;
}

.button-header-home {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    justify-content: end;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.button-header-home button {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #1D9BF0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: @Lucaiano, to me everything seems fine. I think the only problem is that you have set a padding-left to the h2 tag. That's why its not very left aligned.

Comment: the problem is that it shows me in the middle and I want it to show me the h2 at the beginning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved the problem was that in the index.css file, I had this:

```
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    margin: 0px automatic;
 

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The proper syntax is **flex-end** and **flex-start**. What effect do you try to achieve, other than that there are other options like space-between.

Comment: the problem is that it shows me in the middle and I want it to show me the h2 at the beginning

Comment: I have tried it and it works. Like I stated, **flex-between** or **flex-start** or **flex-end** should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this as well and it seems to work fine. You can see the layout from this image with the flex-box outlines added via Dev Tools:

[image]

I'd try writing the CSS as follows and see if it makes a difference. I moved the padding to the container div of the h2 element to match the button container and updated the flexbox terms.

```
.container-header-home {
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.button-header-home {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.logo-header-home {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.logo-header-home h2 {
  color: white;
}

.button-header-home button {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #1d9bf0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: ya lo solucione, el problema era que tenia esto en el index.css * {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
   
}